# How do I update an observable from one namespaced viewModel to another

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This does not work, it sets the defaultView as "bar", but then never updates to "foo" when the ajax request is completed.  I tried to set this as a dependentObservable but didn't have any more luck.  Am I missing something obvious or am I trying to stretch namespaces too far?

```
$.get("/players/summary", function(json) {
  var playerViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json);
  dateViewModel.defaultDate = "foo";
  ko.applyBindings(playerViewModel, 'player');
});

var dateViewModel = {
  defaultDate: ko.observable("bar")
};

ko.applyBindings(dateViewModel, 'date');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting "foo" correctly. You should write:

```
dateViewModel.defaultDate("foo");
```

So you have:

```
$.get("/players/summary", function(json) { 
  var playerViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(json); 
  dateViewModel.defaultDate("foo"); // <--- Set foo using getter setter syntax
  ko.applyBindings(playerViewModel, 'player'); 
}); 

var dateViewModel = { 
  defaultDate: ko.observable("bar") 
}; 

ko.applyBindings(dateViewModel, 'date');
```

This should fix it, but if you still have problems then I would look at definining `dateViewModel` before your `$.get` call.